# How to conditionally load / bundle CSS files in Meteor 1.0?

Tags: meteor

I know this question has been asked before but I'm wondering if something has changed with the advent of 1.0.

I don't want Meteor to automatically bundle together every single CSS file in my app. My admin pages are going to have a completely different CSS than my client-facing pages and using namespaces seems like a really over-complicated solution. How do I have Meteor load certain CSS files on certain pages and NOT load certain CSS files on certain pages?

The same question goes for JS files.

I know someone said this would be useful:

https://github.com/anticoders/meteor-modules

Any comments on this package for conditional CSS and JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just put your CSS files somewhere under /public and manually include them from your templates where required. Everything under /public will NOT get bundled, and the URL will have the /public removed e.g.

1. Create two files:  your_meteor_project/public/one.css  and ......./two.css. These will be available from your client at http://example.com/one.css (i.e. the "public" does not form part of the URL, it's like the document root for using meteor as a plain old web server).

```
    meteor create cssSwitcher
    cd cssSwitcher/
    mkdir public
    echo 'html, body { background-color: red; }' > public/one.css
    echo 'html, body { background-color: blue; }' > public/two.css
```

3. Create a reference to a helper function "appropriateStylesheet" in the head of your HTML :

   HTML template

```html
    <!-- add code to the <body> of the page -->
    <body>
      <h1>Hello!</h1>
      {{> welcomePage}}
    </body>

    <!-- define a template called welcomePage -->
    <template name="welcomePage">
      <!-- add code to the <head> of the page -->
      <head>
        <title>My website!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/{{appropriateStylesheet}}" type="text/css" />
      </head>

      <p>Welcome to my website!</p>
      <button id="red">Red</button>
      <button id="blue">Blue</button>
    </template>
```

3. Create a helper function.

   JavaScript:

```js
    if (Meteor.isClient) {
      Session.set("stylesheet","red.css"); 

      Template.registerHelper("appropriateStylesheet", function() {
        return Session.get("stylesheet");
      });

      Template.welcomePage.events({
        'click #blue' : function() { Session.set("stylesheet","two.css"); },
        'click #red'  : function() { Session.set("stylesheet","one.css"); },
      });

    }
```

You can do exactly the same thing with JS files. Put them under /public and meteor ignores them.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, that's what I figured. So it won't get minified and stuff.

Comment: BTW, you can't directly access the <HEAD> in Meteor. You have to be creative with jQuery.

Comment: Really? The [meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp) say that you can put stuff in the ```<head>``` and it will all get concatenated:

```"Meteor scans all the HTML files in your directory for three top-level elements: <head>, <body>, and <template>. The head and body sections are separately concatenated into a single head and body, which are transmitted to the client on initial page load."```

I'm not saying you're wrong, just that the docs don't seem to tally.

Comment: Bah, youre right. However, <body> is something that meteor won't, or didn't, do. For example, people have been having a hard time assigning classes to the body tag. At least before, if you put the body tag in a template your app would error out.

Comment: Congratulations, you've just added `<link type="text/css" href="{{appropriateStylesheet}}" rel="stylesheet">` to your page! @cobberboy that's why the doc was pretty clear for this. Downvoting.

Comment: @ErdalG. Wow. Have a nice day.

Comment: Sorry for the tone, didn't mean to be rude @cobberboy  It just annoyed me because I did what you said and it didn't work at all...

Comment: @ErdalG. The <head> elements need to be in a template. I'll update the answer accordingly. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @cobberboy I just tried your example, and after a quick check w/ firebug, the `<title>` and the `<link>` are in the `<body>` :/