# Giving native look to a meteor/cordova app with css, conditioning it to the platform build

Tags: css, cordova, meteor

I am developing an hybrid mobile app with Meteor and Cordova, and in order to have a native look I want to use two different stylesheets: [Bootstrap material design](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design) for android  and [Ratchet](http://goratchet.com/) for IOS.

What is the simplest way to conditionally include the respective css and javascript files? i.e. the command:

```
 meteor run ios
```

should generate an app with the ios css, while:

```
 meteor run android
```

should generate the app with android css.

If there is no simple way, is the Meteor team working on this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to conditionally load / bundle CSS files in Meteor 1.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263232/how-to-conditionally-load-bundle-css-files-in-meteor-1-0)

Comment: No. That question is about using different stylesheets for different pages. My question asks how to globally apply different stylesheets to different cordova  builds.

Comment: well yeah, but the approach taken in that question should work for you as well. It might only be one way of solving your problem, but I believe it's not a bad one at all.

Comment: Sorry no, that solution is not at all relevant. It's actually wrong because you cannot put variables in the head. The head tag is not dynamic in Meteor.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the merges-folder is for. Take a look at the [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/guide/cli/). Just search for *Using merges to Customize Each Platform*...

Comment: The answer is useful, however in Meteor the Cordova project is created automatically at build time. It remains to be seen how to tell the build system to copy the relevant files in the merges directory.